# Is there a way to safely scrape a single-page application (SPA) from the browser?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, single-page-application, puppeteer, domparser

I've built a small tool to scrape metadata from web pages within the web browser using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). This works well for a lot of sites, but some pages, like [a tweet page](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1245427009016205319), do not have their metadata added until the attached JavaScript has loaded the data.

I know that I could setup some sort of proxy server running [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer), but I'm looking for a solution that **would work directly in the browser**.

Answer (score -1):

[Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) is a really great tool for scraping. It is primarily an end-to-end testing tool for web sites of all sorts (including SPAs), but what is end-to-end testing if it is not just fancy web scraping?

I've used Protractor to scrape dozens of sites in the past and it works flawlessly. Is easy to schedule, can run headless Chrome, or phantomJS so you don't even see the pages loading.

Comment: This seems to startup a web server, but it appear to run within a webpage, or am I missing something?

Comment: (correction): and does *not* appear to run within a webpage